# OpenGL - SRGB vs floating point texture

Tags: opengl, srgb

Generally speaking, I understand the concepts of the linear color space, sRGB colorspace, gamma-correction and how monitors displays colors - gamma curve.  When I create a texture in the graphics program like a GIMP sRGB colorspace is used by default. Next when I read that texture in the OpenGL application I should convert the sRGB to the linear color space in order to get  a correct mipmaps or perform postprocessing. When I call `glTexImage2D` with the internal texture format set to `GL_SRGB` I get an automatic conversion from the sRGB to the linear color space when reading that texture. Before rendering to the default framebuffer I should apply a gamma correction to the linear color space to get a correct color output. Could you please explain why OpenGL doesn't support a SRGB floating point textures like GL_SRGB32F ?